# How to determine which channels are avaiable for the client in the Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, servicebus

Hello,

I’m building a program with the Azure AppFabric Service Bus. My intention is to exposure multiple devices though the Service Bus with the same namespace. Every device creates a connection through the Service Bus with a different ‘Service path’ using the ‘ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri’ method. Example:First host:Uri relayAddress1 = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("https", "MyNamespace", "MyServicePath1");Second host:Uri relayAddress2 = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri("https", "MyNamespace", "MyServicePath2");I wonder if it is possible to retrieve information from the Service Bus, which host connections are available. I can imagine that “MyServicePath1”, “MyServicePath2” and “MyServicePath4” are available but “MyServicePath3” is not. On the client side I could try to open 4 channels to each host and catch the CommunicationException to determine if the host is available, but that doesn’t feel very efficient. Is there a way to achieve this without catching exceptions?Thanks in advance,Stan Verdiesen

Answer (score 2):

Hi Sandrino Di Mattia,

Thank you for your quick response. I've tried your solution with success! Thanks again.

For the completeness, my implementation:

***The DiscoveryMode property on the service host:***

```cs
        Uri relayAddress = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri(Uri.UriSchemeHttps, "MyNamespace", "MyServicePath1");

        BasicHttpRelayBinding relayBinding = new BasicHttpRelayBinding();

        ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ExternalDataExchangerTestServer));
        ServiceEndpoint endPoint = serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IExternalDataExchanger), relayBinding, relayAddress);

        endPoint.Behaviors.Add(new TransportClientEndpointBehavior { TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedSecretTokenProvider("YourName", "YourKey") });
        endPoint.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceRegistrySettings { DiscoveryMode = DiscoveryType.Public });

        serviceHost.Open();
```

***A solution to read the atom feed by code:***

```cs
  public static List<string> GetAvailableServiceBusHosts(string serviceNamespace)
  {
     if (serviceNamespace == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("serviceNamespace");

     var relayAddress = ServiceBusEnvironment.CreateServiceUri(Uri.UriSchemeHttps, serviceNamespace, string.Empty);

     var availableHosts = new List<string>();

     var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(relayAddress);

     httpWebRequest.Proxy = null;
     httpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
     httpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;

     using (var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
     {
        using (var responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
           if (responseStream == null)
              throw new NullReferenceException("responseStream");

           var atomFormatter = new Atom10FeedFormatter();

           var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(responseStream);
           atomFormatter.ReadFrom(xmlReader);

           var syndicationFeed = atomFormatter.Feed;

           foreach (var syndicationItem in syndicationFeed.Items)
           {
              availableHosts.Add(syndicationItem.Title.Text);
           }

           return availableHosts;
        }
     }
  }
```

I hope this helps other people!

Answer (score 1):

If you set the [DiscoveryMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.servicebus.serviceregistrysettings.discoverymode) of your **ServiceRegistrySettings** to **Public** your service will be available in the atom feed. Once you've done this you can get a list of services by accessing the namespace url: http://**service-namespace**.servicebus.windows.net/

Reference: [How to: Discover and Expose a Service Bus Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee706696)